# How to format a negative number red within a mixed formula result

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, text-formatting, google-sheets-cell-format

We use the following formula:

`="Stu/W: " & TEXT((A$2/B2),"[Red]#,###,##0.00") &"€"`

and wish to have the resulting negative currency numbers colored red and positive blue.

[image]

Unfortunately neither this or other combinations we tried works. Neither did we find a solution using Conditional Formatting.
How can we have the resulting negative currency numbers colored red as well as the positive blue?

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/131161/186471

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/127678/186471

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reference a cell while keeping its color formatting?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/127674/how-to-reference-a-cell-while-keeping-its-color-formatting)

Comment: The above mentioned link by serenesat is NOT a duplicate. Furthermore the answer by user0 provided neither an answer or "was the most helpful in finding a solution" to do this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pull this off automatically in Google Sheets with formulas, conditional rules nor even with a script. Multicolour text is not supported to be achieved other than setting it up manually on non-formula output.

But if you really want:

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

Which isn't so pretty so one drawing per row with a white background would look like this:

[image: 0]

[image: 0]