# How to reference a cell while keeping its color formatting?

Tags: google-sheets, text-formatting

Is it possible to reference a cell which contains "ABC" where B is blue and C is yellow while keeping the color formatting?
Assume A1 contains the colored text, then I want B1 to refer to A1 and maintain the colors.

[A similar question was asked 3 years ago](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/50409/cell-reference-with-colour-formatting), but the answer seems to be not working anymore.

Comment: [Meta question about this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327002/duplicate-question-answers-no-longer-work-apply-new-user-cannot-assign-bounty-t)

Comment: @JanDoggen this is not a duplicate. the link in Q is mistakenly referenced as "something similar from past" but it's not. This Q deals with **multiple** colors in one single cell (which is not possible to achieve) while referenced post deals with a single color for font and a single color for the background (which is still possible to achieve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transferring multiple individual colors from in-one-cell to another cell is not possible at this current version of the Google Sheets (nor at any previous versions):

[image: 0]

Comment: There was a questions 2~3 years ago which is similar to this one. I tried to duplicate the answers but it seems like they no longer working.
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/50409/cell-reference-with-colour-formatting

Comment: @WeiZheng indeed, however, that is something else. having ABC in more than 1 color is not possible to reference anyhow. on the other hand, referencing cell which has 1 font color and 1 background color is possible via scripting to be referenced

Comment: oh I see, thanks for the help!