# Partial cell formatting with CONCATENATE in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, formatting, concatenate, google-sheets-cell-format

Is there a way to format partially using `CONCATENATE` in Google Sheets?

For example, `=CONCATENATE("*", Sheet1!A1, Sheet1!B1)`, and I want to make the `*` bolded or blue in color or something else.

I realize that I could either:

1. Split it across multiple cells and control the color (this does not work for the sheet I am working on because of all else that is going on in the sheet.  To begin with, I have merged two cells in order to fit the text.  Unmerging would cause the text to be obstructed.  Changing the column width would mess with other entries in the same column.)
2. Manually convert it to plain text and make the necessary formatting changes.  But that too manual.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/127678/186471

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/130191/186471

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comments.  I've upvoted the answer and the comments.  But, I'm not sure I want to accept the answer because it's not a solution and it's not the case that this is impossible to achieve.  It is just that we don't know of a way today.  Tomorrow, google may add a feature or someone may find a way around what's there in order to accomplish this.  Open to other thoughts.  Also, the links above are slightly different.  This question is for concatenate.  127678 is for a reference and 130191 is for conditional formatting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reference a cell while keeping its color formatting?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/127674/how-to-reference-a-cell-while-keeping-its-color-formatting)

Answer (score 2):

If you are after this then it's **not** possible:

[image: 0]

You can do this **only** manually.

---

If you just want more visible star you can use one of these instead like:

```
=CONCATENATE("✱", Sheet1!A1, Sheet1!B1)
```

[image: 0]

## ```
✱ ★ ☆ ✢ ✥ ✦ ✧ ❂ ❉ ✯ ✰ ✲ ✴ ✵ ✶ ✷ ✸ ❇ ✩ ✪ ✫ ✬ 
✭ ✹ ✺ ✻ ✼ ❈ ✮ ✡ ✾ ✿ ❀ ❁ ❃ ❊ ❋ ✣ ✤ ✽ ⁂ ⁑ ✳ 
❄ ❆ ❅ ⋆ ≛ ☪
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm after unfortunately.